# generate makefile with qmake that have additional dependency for MS VS

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Visual Studio project that is made with qmake (qmake -tp vc), it's a lib, and it uses win32 socket function (setsockopt), so I need include "Ws2_32.lib".

but if I do something like

```
POST_TARGETDEPS  += Ws2_32.lib
```

it's not written to Visual Studio project file. Problem for me, that I have few app type projects that includes this lib, and I would be better if I don't need set additional lines in .pro files for these projects.

So my question is, what directive/variable I need to use in .pro file, so lib dependency ends in Visual Studio project files?

Solved:
I didn't found how to create Visual Studio project file for lib with additional dependency, but as workaround I added LIB definition in .pri file which is included in all application type projects, so I don't need to add this lib to each project manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LIBS`:

```
win32:LIBS += -lWs2_32
```

Comment: this was my first try, but it not helps. By not helps I mean it is not added in "Additional Dependencies" list in VS project (after regenerating project file of course)

Comment: Works for me. Do you have a diff of the solution/project file before and after using LIBS?

Comment: Nop, I don't have any for that project. It works for exe ("TEMPLATE = app") but not for lib ("TEMPLATE = lib")

Comment: When this lib is included, there of course are other projects, but I want to generate VS project file with including "ws2_32" lib, and as standalone lib it doesn't have any other .pro (or other type) of projects include.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to carry over aka propagate the Ws2_32 to the other apps? Since this Ws2_32 is needed for the linker, it can't be specified only for the library. A workaround is to place it in a simple mylib_deps.pri and then include that .pri from other .pro files.

Comment: yes, if there will be no other way I will stay with .pri file, there is one for some flags, so it probably would not be very bad have lib included.